# cannot be found: com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo

Tags: ant, jsch

I am trying to use the Ant `<scp>` task in my buildfile. It gives me an error every time I run the target:

```
cannot be found: com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo
```

I have read some posts that talk about having this issue with Ant 1.7. Some of the posts are talking about removing the `ant-jsch.jar` files from the ant_home lib. Unfortunately I can't do that as the ant_home is common across lot of other projects and I can't remove or update any jar files from the lib directory.

Is there a way that I can solve this issue purely using Ant configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ant-jsch.jar` contains ssh related tasks developed by Apache Ant team, while `jsch.jar` contains the jsch library which is the dependency of those ssh tasks.

So do a little check: check if `jsch.jar` is in your `$ANT_HOME/lib` and also check if the jar contains `UserInfo.class`.

If one of above happens, download the latest version of `jsch.jar` and put it in `$ANT_HOME/lib`.

I am currently using Ant 1.8.4 with a `jsch.jar` downloaded last year without any problem.

---

Update:

Check this page first:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks

Please note that `<scp>` and other ssh tasks (the ant-jsch.jar) are included in the Ant binary distribution by default. You don't need to write `<taskdef>` to use `<scp>` because it is included in Ant's lib directory by default. I recommend you to put `jsch.jar` in that directory with the following points:

1. These ssh tasks don't support classpath def, that is to say, you can't define a `<classpath>` pointing to `jsch.jar` and then reference to it in an ssh task.
2. Also you can put `jsch.jar` in any directory included in your system's CLASSPATH environment variable, but it is not a good practice.
3. We usually put a task and its dependency in the same directory.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I have the jsch jar file but its not in ANT_HOME/lib directory. Its under a separate directory. Is there a way to load that jar file from different location. If I use classpath task its going to use a different class loader right. Sorry please mind my limited knowledge about ant.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for your help. It works if I have the jar in the lib directory.

Comment: Hi there, I have found an alternative way of providing the jsch.jar to the ant task by using -lib command line argument. I had to do this as I dont have budget for tools team to update their cots directory to add a new jar. Wish we had better tools team people that actually work!